# How to disable scroll on Safari? Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, safari

I am trying to disable scroll when the navbar menu is open on mobile, it works perfectly on chrome but not on safari.

I have seen that many people have similar problems on this browser, as it doesn´t all work the same way.

I am using this useEffect code to disable the scroll on chrome:

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => setOpen(!isOpen);

  useEffect(() =>{
    document.body.style.overflowY = isOpen ? 'hidden' : 'auto';
  }, [isOpen])

  return (
<header className="relative bg-black">
        <div className=""></div>

{isOpen && (
          <div className=""></div>
```

What can I change this to, in order to keep it all working as intended on chrome but also work properly on safari? If anyone could help that  would be great!

Comment: You can try applying this style not to the `<body>`, but to the root element of the app (for Nextjs I believe it's a `<div id="__next">`, but you can inspect your particular app), so try something like `document.getElementById("__next").style.overflowY = isOpen ? 'hidden' : 'auto';`

Comment: Is this affecting safari on macos or ios?

Comment: @Meron I have only tried it on ios devices, not macOS as I don´t have anything.

Comment: @AlexCotton This might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: @tromgy I have tried that but haven´t had any success

Comment: @AlexCotton, as it turned out for this trick to work, the "root" element must have the height specified. This might or might not work for your case. But you can use this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-morning-tjfeix?file=/pages/index.js) for reference.